# Regex to capture patterns using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin, wdio-v5

I am new to automation ! I use wdio5 , cucumber and selenium framework with  gherkin language . I need to write a step file using JavaScript for the gherkin feature that needs to add these patterns

Examples

52.27
.27
2.27

I hope I asked the question correctly!! Junior developer in the house

Help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need a regex pattern to match the numbers you shared.

Here is an example of such a pattern:

```
/^[-+]?((\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?))$/
```

Where `[-+]?` to match the leading `+/-` sign, `(\.\d+)` to match the numbers with a leadiinig `.`, and `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` to match full numbers.

Should match the numbers like: `'-1', '+1', '50', '.27', '2.27'`

Snippet:

```js
const testNumbers = ['-1', '+1', '50', '.27', '2.27'];
const pattern = /^[-+]?((\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?))$/;

const isAllMatched = testNumbers.every(testNumber => testNumber === testNumber.match(pattern)?.[0]);

console.log('isAllMatched: ', isAllMatched);
```